# stop-and-wait efficiency calculation

Tags: performance, propagation

I have an exercise for school and the teacher didnt teach us what we need to know so i was searching the internet to find a solution. Since i am not sure if i am right , can you please see the question and the answer and tell me if i am right?
Here it goes.

A channel has a data rate of 10 kbps. The transmitted frames are sized
550 bit and the propagation  is 20 msec. Errors do not exist.
Since STOP-AND-WAIT protocol is used  how large should the confirmation size be in order to have 55% efficiency?

I found that the efficiency type is efficiency = Tdata/(Tdata + 2*Tprop) and Tdata = DataFrameSize/transmission speed.

Solving that i find that the efficiency is  57%.

So the question asks how the frame size changes in order to have efficiency 55%?

If yes, doing the math that should be 488,88 bits,right?

Am i right or the question asks something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the equation assumes a acknowledgment packet with a size of zero and no processing time. The denominator of this equation must be extended to include also the transmission time (TAck)

So the full type is Ttotal=TData+Tprop+TAck+Tprop

Solving for TAck and put the answer into the efficiency type.